# Angular Using Wrong URL for querying MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, angular7

I have this Angular 7 app that was working fine until I decided to move my logic out of the app.component.ts file into a new login.component.ts file. Ever since I did this, when I try and login and the app queries the database, it uses the wrong url--4200 instead of 3000. I set up a proxy.conf.json file like this:

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false
    }
 }
```

This actually was already set up before I made the switch out of my app.component.ts file. I didn't make any other changes than reconnecting everything from the move to another component. I can't find where Angular is pointed to localhost:4200 instead of 3000. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance. Banging my head against the wall. By the by my OS is Windows 10 running VS Code.

Here's the error of my next issue:

```
VM623:37 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at 
LoginComponent.push../src/app/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.toPrint
```

And here are the two functions involved with this error:

```
toPrint(match) {
  return `Name: ${this.match[0].name} Checking: ${this.match[0].checking} 
Savings: ${this.match[0].savings}`
}

printUserData(match){
this.buttonPressed = true;
return  this.loginComponent.toPrint(match);
}
```

Comment: Hi bill , Did you put proxy configurations in angular.json file ..??

Comment: It is still happening. I am mystified what is causing this. I thought I reconfigured the proxy.conf.json file but it did not work. I hope someone else has some ideas.

Comment: bill ,can you please share your angular.json file

Comment: The file is too big to share Samarth. What do you want to know? I don't have any config options in there. They are in the proxy.conf.json file as I said above.

Comment: ok just share you code of serve section in angular.json file

Comment: Thanks Samarth. It fixed part of the problem. Now I have another issue with values not being returned from the DB.

Comment: haha, I thought according to your question proxy config url is the only problem. By the way i need more details about backend error or maybe code cause guessing like that is impossible. I am gonna post your first problem solution on answers so that it can be benificial to others :) .

Comment: @SamarthSaxena I updated to show what else I was having trouble with--see above. Thanks Samarth. Let me know if you have any ideas. I'll accept your answer as well here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189248/discussion-between-samarth-saxena-and-bill-wagner).

Answer (score 1):

Just include your proxy configurations in angular.json file so that at the time when you run your application it run your proxy as well.

Example -

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "movie-analysis:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "movie-analysis:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix things. I am still getting the 404 message.